# Ubuntu 10.10 running slow, going grey and shaking

Tags: command-line

My computer: 3200+ AMD Sempron Processor 512 MB 100GB

From time to time Ubuntu runs incredibly slow, the screen goes grey and shakes up and down when I'm browsing a site. I hope this enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Most likely your Browser is eating up a lot of resources or it could be another process. I would run the 'top' program and share the results to this post. This may give you a pointer as to what is causing the performance drag.

Answer (score 1):

If you log off and back on (not reboot) then it is very likely that your browser or some other program is eating resources.  I leave my browser open for weeks on end and some sites start sucking resources.  I close and re-open the browser and all is good again.